# How do I make Visual Studio ignore "Microsoft Public Symbols"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm [using JetBrains dotPeek as a symbol server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/2016.2/Using_product_as_a_Symbol_Server.html) to get inside of Visual Studio and debug a language extension, and it works really well, for the most part.  But I've got an exception occurring inside of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.dll`, and for some reason I can't decompile that, because VS keeps loading a PDB from "Microsoft Public Symbols" instead of going to the dotPeek server, even though I've explicitly unchecked "Microsoft Symbol Server" as a valid location to load from.  (Apparently those are different things?)

Is there any way to get VS to never, under any circumstances, load symbol files from Microsoft's servers, no matter how common or "public" the assembly may be?